# My Facebook Messenger say "Online - Active Now" despite my phones being offline

Tags: facebook-messenger

My friend connects with me via the Facebook Messenger application.  A few days ago, after it was turned off, she checked if she had messages from me and found out that I was online "Active now" many times.

There is no way that I was online because I closed all of my applications when I work and had been in meetings (although my phones were, in fact, offline).

Can anyone explain why the app lists me as being online and active?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a mobile app.

Comment: I will be happy to migrate this for you now that I've cleaned it up a bit, but is this related to the iPhone app or the Android one?

Answer (score 0):

> There is no way that I was online because I closed all of my
>   applications when I work and had been in meetings (although my phones
>   were, in fact, offline).
>
> Can anyone explain why the app lists me as being online and active?

There are two possibilities,

1. Your account was hacked and someone else logged into it. If you are still able to access your account, you should change your password. (It is recommended to use stronger passwords with both numbers and letters. E.g. **a3d2co4@#$*@**)
2. Facebook mistakenly showed you as active. It is not uncommon.